# How to get the product taxonomy on woocommerce metadata order

Tags: wordpress, metadata, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy

I'm using a hook with `woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta` to get the taxonomy and the categories of the current product inside the order metadata at my template's functions.php. But it doesn't work, this is the problem:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items()` on boolean in `functions.php:402`

**Important! >** The product is a custom post done with the [WP Fundraising Donation plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fundraising-donation/), so the problem is to call the custom post taxonomy because it is different than the product taxonomy.

```
    // GET TAXONOMY
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'get_the_terms_hook', 10, 3 );
    function get_the_terms_hook ( $item_id, $item, $post) {
     
    // Get $product object from $order / $order_id  
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); // this is the line 402
      
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
      
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
      
        // Now you have access to (see above)...
        $product->get_categories();
        $product->get_category_ids();
        $product->get_tag_ids();
      
    }
```

Comment: `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`
where is `$order_id` specified?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61203049/11987538) answer, 
this shows you how to access the product object (
the 3rd parameter) and its properties

Comment: You Mean > if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ) { // Get product id $product_id = $product->get_id(); to check the method to get the current product ID?

Comment: I mean `$product->get_...`, a foreach loop to get the products out of the `$order` object is not necessary because you already have access to the `$product` object. 
Indeed, in the answer I am referring to, the product ID is obtained through the  `$product` object, but this can be any property

Comment: Ok, I understand, but my problem is that I'm using a custom post with the WP fundraising plugin, that has a different taxonomy that the product, so this is my principal problem to call the categories because o don't know if I have to call `$post` or `$product`

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing process on order thank you then this will help you. Check the content as well as comment too.
[Click Here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/)

Comment: I tried but the error still there, I was thinking that but my problem is that I'm using a custom post with the WP fundraising plugin, that has a different taxonomy that the product, so this is my principal problem to call the specific categories form the custom post or the product

Comment: at which specific instance you would like to execute this code? It seems that on given action hook, `get_items` is throwing fatal error and further  execution of the code is fail

Comment: I need this hook to link the category to the product/custom-post title at the order metadata to migrate this information. The Hook is at the theme's functions. Thanks!

Comment: When you need this process need to be done? on order update? or order placed from frontside? or somewhere else? It is important where and which hook you are executing

Comment: if you are doing process on order thank you then this will help you. Check the content as well as comment too. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: Thanks, I think that the right moment to do it is when order is complete / payment complete to get the custom post/product category and migrate to CRM